# var that = this VS dojo.hitch()

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it better to use **var that = this**;

```
var that = this;
array.forEach( tabPages, function ( tabPage, index ) {
  that.layerTabPageClose(tabPage.id, true);
  ...
});
```

or to use **lang.hitch()** instead

```
array.forEach( tabPages, lang.hitch( this, function ( tabPage, index ) {
  this.layerTabPageClose(tabPage.id, true);
  ...
}));
```

Which one is better and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this **particular** case, neither; use the third argument to Dojo's [`array.forEach`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/array.html#foreach) instead:

```
array.forEach(tabPages, function ( tabPage, index ) {
  this.layerTabPageClose(tabPage.id, true);
  ...
}, this);
// ^^^^
```

Or use the browser's built-in [`Array#forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) (as of ES5) and its second argument:

```
tabPages.forEach(function ( tabPage, index ) { // <== Note change
  this.layerTabPageClose(tabPage.id, true);
  ...
}, this);
// ^^^^
```

**In the general case:**

If you're creating a function in the context where you're doing this (and you'd have to, for the `var that = this` to be an option), it doesn't matter and is entirely a matter of style.

If you *aren't*, you need to use `lang.hitch` or ES5's [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually rather a personal choice you can make. If you rather want to be able to use the context everywhere, then you should probably use `dojo/_base/lang::hitch()`, so that you can work with the `this` context all the time.

The other choice is to work with an extra variable on the (parent) scope, like `that` or `vm` (often seen with AngularJS), but both are great.

The only suggestion I would make is that you do the same thing through your entire codebase. If you sometimes work with a scope variable and other times you work with `lang.hitch()` then it will only lead to confusion.

---

Anyways, some methods, like `dojo/_base/array` already allow you to include the context:

> forEach(arr,callback,thisObject)

API Docs: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/_base/array

So that's an even better solution in these cases.